# Python urllib response returns file with added blank lines

Tags: python, xml, httprequest, response, urllib

While testing services I created a function in python that call http request on access point URL. Response is saved to the file in a given path.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.response
import urllib.parse


def get_response(service_access_point, request_parameters, response_file_path):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(service_access_point.format(request_parameters))
    res = req.read().decode('utf-8')
    response_file = open(response_file_path, 'w')
    response_file.write(res)
    response_file.flush()
    response_file.close()
```

This function shall call request and return xml file. It does, but between every two lines is a new blank line added.

```
<FeatureCollection timeStamp="2015-05-21T17:44:24" numberMatched="1637" numberReturned="1637" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0">

 <boundedBy>

   <Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514" srsDimension="2">

      <lowerCorner>-559647.09 -1108439.9</lowerCorner>

      <upperCorner>-555782.49 -1104336.04</upperCorner>

   </Envelope>

</boundedBy>

<member>

  <Address gml:id="AD.16238842">
     ...
  </Address>

</member>
```

In this form it is impossible to validate file or open it in some programms (GIS etc.). Is it possible to force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
...
res = req.read().decode('utf-8')
res = "".join(filter(str.strip, res.split('\n'))) # remove blank lines
response_file = open(response_file_path, 'w')
response_file.write(res)
...
```

This is a bit functional style, if you like it.